# Enter a number or Q to quit

Tags: c#

Hi all I have been having some problems with a task I have been set

The first part of the task was to output a price table with the following rules:

The price for up to 50 is £5 each. For between 51 and 80, the price is £4 each, while for between 81 and 100 the price is a rock bottom £2.50 each.
Using loop structures and selection statements (if.. etc) your program should output a widget price chart for widgets in multiples of 10 up to 100.

I have done this however the second part of the task has me stumped 
after the table has been output to input a number of widgets. You should then calculate the cost and output the value. If the user enters ‘q’ or ‘Q’, the program should terminate.

Here is the full code

```
using System;
namespace w5Task3
{
class Program
    { public static void Main ( string[] args )
            {

            double PriceEach1 = 5;
            double PriceEach2 = 4;
            double PriceEach3 = 2.50;
            double Quantity = 10;
            int UserOrder=0;

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nBelow is the price chart:\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("WidgetQuantity\t\t\tPrice\n");
            while (Quantity <=100)

                {   

                    double Price1 = PriceEach1*Quantity;
                    double Price2 = PriceEach2*Quantity;
                    double Price3 = PriceEach3*Quantity;


                        if (Quantity <=50)      
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t\t\t{1:C}", Quantity, Price1);
                    }


                        if(Quantity >=51 && Quantity <=80)      
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t\t\t{1:C}", Quantity, Price2);
                    }


                        if (Quantity >80 && Quantity <=100)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine ("\t{0}\t\t\t{1:C}",Quantity, Price3);                        
                    }
                Quantity +=10;
                }


            while (UserOrder >=0)
                {
                    try
                        {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of widgets you would like to purchase or press q to quit");
                        string temp = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (temp =="q") break;
                        if (temp =="Q") break;

                        int.TryParse(temp, out UserOrder);

                        double UserPrice;

                        if (UserOrder <=50)
                            {
                                UserPrice = UserOrder*5;
                                Console.WriteLine("The price is {0:C}",UserPrice);
                            }

                        if (UserOrder >=51 && UserOrder <=80)
                            {
                                UserPrice = UserOrder*4;
                                Console.WriteLine("The price is {0:C}",UserPrice");
                            }

                        if (UserOrder >80)
                            {
                                UserPrice = UserOrder*2.5;
                                Console.WriteLine("The price is {0:C}",UserPrice");
                            }


                        }
                            catch(Exception)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value. Please enter a number or press q to quit");
                                }
                }



            }
    }
```

The part I am having issues with is:

```
                while (UserOrder >=0)
                {
                    try
                        {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of widgets you would like to purchase or press q to quit");
                        string temp = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (temp =="q") break;
                        if (temp =="Q") break;

                        int.TryParse(temp, out UserOrder);

                        double UserPrice;

                        if (UserOrder <=50)
                            {
                                UserPrice = UserOrder*5;
                                Console.WriteLine("The price is {0:C}",UserPrice);
                            }

                        if (UserOrder >=51 && UserOrder <=80)
                            {
                                UserPrice = UserOrder*4;
                                Console.WriteLine("The price is {0:C}",UserPrice");
                            }

                        if (UserOrder >80)
                            {
                                UserPrice = UserOrder*2.5;
                                Console.WriteLine("The price is {0:C}",UserPrice");
                            }


                        }
                            catch(Exception)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value. Please enter a number or press q to quit");
                                }
                }
}
```

I can get the program to quit or do one UserPrice but it is when I need to make it change the price dependent on the amount ordered.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what (or if) your question is, if you have one please clarify.  But I think you're asking us to do your homework for you.. =)

Comment: If you are going to use `int.TryParse` then you don't need the `try...catch` block. `TryParse` returns a bool which you should test. If it's false, then the input couldn't be parsed.

Comment: The problem is when I compile, my if statements which determine the cost of them item due to amount, I get the message newline in constant . Sorry for any confusion =P But yes this is a task set while at uni however my lecture notes reveal nothing about terminating a program =(

Comment: Qustions like these are why I like to push the SSCCE, the Small Self-Contained Complete Example.    Nobody want's to wade through a hundred of lines of code to try to find what your problem might be

Comment: also, writing `return;` from your `main` method should terminate the program

Comment: Instead of using 'If' statements in this piece of code 'd try using a Case statement to determine what you do for each price bracket.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Got a lot of useful information really quick and my program compiles and works. Got a lot of good ideas too, I'm still getting my head around 100 solutions to one problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have newlines in your constant expressions at lines 67 and 73!

Fix those, and it all runs fine.

Comment: Thanks alot ! Can't believe I missed that been staring at this for about 2 hours now :( Even missed what the error code was telling me on microsoft webpage. I think it might be time for more coffee

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is the quote after UserPrice on rows 64 and 70..

```
Console.WriteLine("The price is {0:C}",UserPrice");
```

remove it

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to adjust `UserOrder` after you calculate the price for that portion of the order.  You can go in either direction, but it basically looks like:

```
if (HasThisQuantityRange)
{
   Total += ThisAmount * (Lower of: ThisQuantity or UserOrder);
   UserOrder -= (Lower of: ThisQuantity or UserOrder);
}

if (UserOrder > 0 && HasAdjustedQuantityRange)
{
   Total += ThisAmount * (Lower of: ThisQuantity or UserOrder);
   UserOrder -= (Lower of: ThisQuantity or UserOrder);
}
```

and so on.

Obviously, this is all pseudocode, and you'll need to implement it yourself, but this will hopefully get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: how did you figure out the question? :)

Comment: @trippino - I looked for the flaw in the logic, based on the stated goal.  Although, based on the comment that was added later, I clearly targeted the wrong problem. Alas.

Comment: And, on further reading, I'm not even sure that my interpretation of the assignment was accurate.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion with the question, or lack of. Thanks for the help didn't use it this time but will look at this way in future as it looks simpler and more compact than my way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly the problem you're having is. Are you struggling to get the right calculation for the order or is the Quit behavior not acting in the way that you're expecting.

In general I think its bad form to use a transient variable like that for your while loop condition. When I want a console app to repeat I typically set up a variable specifically used for the loop condition like this:

```
bool isRunning = true;
while (isRunning)
{
     ....
```

Then when you check for your input

```
if (temp.ToUpper() == "Q")
{
     isRunning = false;
     break;
}
```

Comment: Just read your comment regarding the newline in constant error. Typically on StackOverflow it helps a lot when you post specific errors or issues in the title and in your original post as they point to the root of the issue. Josh Greifer's answer will show you to to fix it and it had nothing to do with your quit logic or orderprice logic

Comment: Thank for the tip will take it into account in future. Just had to much info I think. Thought people would need to see the problem in context... Turns out I'm just blind.