# Using a q to quit the program

Tags: c#

asking the user after the table has been output to 
input a number of widgets. You should then calculate the cost and output the value. 
If the user enters ‘q’ or ‘Q’, the program should terminate

what code could I use to quit the program?

Comment: `Environment.Exit` or `return;`

Comment: What kind of program is this? WinForms, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, console??? You are going to have give us more info.

Comment: What have you tried, what kind of program? `Console.ReadKey()`? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Is this homework? Sounds like homework...

Comment: @Lirik, does that make a differnce?

Comment: @Jodrell: yes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @caesay, or no, either way I'd like to see some effort and detail before providing an answer.

Comment: @Jodrell yes it does... homework questions usually have more specific requirements and the OP is often limited as to what is a valid solution. The OP might be offered a solution which she/he has not learned about yet, that is specifically excluded, that uses third party libraries which are not available to the instructor, etc. etc.

Comment: @JesseCarter: Hooray for Canada! :)

Comment: I knew that I've seen this before somewhere. Must be 2 people from the same class both looking for answers :P
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457411/enter-a-number-or-q-to-quit/13457646#13457646

Answer (score 5):

number of ways to do that:

```
Application.Exit;
```

or

```
System.Environment.Exit( exitCode );
```

It really depends on your environment, which you did not specify.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Application.Exit()` does not work on a console app, which this likely is.

Comment: @JonB Duly noted, thansk. But since OP did not specify, I tried to give a broader anwer.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use any specific code to quit the program at all.  Some methods exist, but they should be reserved for exceptional circumstances.  (This isn't an exceptional circumstance.)

What you *should* do is simply keep the program running as long as they *don't* want to quit.  Many console programs will end up with a loop such as this:

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

while(userInput != quitCommand)
{
    //Do stuff with user input

    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
}

//end of program.
```

Whenever possible (and it's quite possible here) your program should end simply because the call to your `Main` method reached the end, normally.

Comment: This is a much better answer +1

Comment: There is a better way to do this loop in my opinion... `while((userInput = Console.ReadLine()) != quitCommand) { .. }` That way, you dont have to worry about assigning it at the end and the beginning.

Comment: @caesay I make a point of avoiding side effects in conditional expressions; it makes for less readable code.

Comment: +1. I'd move check inside loop if there are more commands to handle (q = quit, l = list,...). Or go all the way with something like `foreach(var input in ReadInputCommandsAsEnumeration()){if (input == quitCommand) break;...}`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I specifically wouldn't do that.  The `while` loop covers the quit condition, and inside of it there would be a `switch` on all of the other possible commands.  This is specifically avoiding using a `break` as it makes it hard to tell when the loop ends when reading from the beginning (you need to try to find all possible jump operators in the loop).